# Sentry Flutter Plugin : cannot find symbol

Tags: flutter, sentry

Since I have upgraded flutter, I am getting this error :

> /android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:179:
> error: cannot find symbol
> flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin());
> ^   symbol:   class SentryFlutterPlugin   location: package io.sentry.flutter

I have upgraded all plugins and run flutter clean.

Build.gradle : implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:6.34.0'

Comment: Tthe last user who encountered this solved this with flutter clean and removing GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

Comment: I just did it, it is not resolving the issue :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved using [sentry](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry) plugin instead of [sentry_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter) plugin

Comment: I see that Sentry is not using io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin(); but why Sentry Flutter does ?

Answer (score 3):

Consider running `flutter clean` in the flutter project you are facing such error. Then, run the application again.

Comment: As I said in my description, flutter clean did not help

Comment: In my case this solved the problem.